# Ошибка сервлета JSP: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat, jstl

При попытке подключения JSTL к JSP-файлу, я получаю следующие ошибки.

В браузере:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate 
TagLibraryValidator class: [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоли:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() ��� �������� [jsp] � ��������� 
� ����� [/web] �������� ���������� 
[org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate 
TagLibraryValidator class: 
[org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV]] � �������������
java.lang.ClassCastException: class 
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV cannot be cast to class 
jakarta.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator 
(org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV is in unnamed module of
loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @4b21844c; 
jakarta.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator is in unnamed module of 
loader java.net.URLClassLoader @31221be2)
```

Как я понял, ошибка может быть из-за конфликта зависимостей maven, однако как бы я не экспериментировал, исправить ошибку не получается.

Я использую Tomcat 10.1.13 и maven 3.9.4.
Список моих maven-зависимостей:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>      
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Ну, тут сразу же видно подключение и javax, и jakarta, а это уже точно плохо. Надо оставить что-то одно. Так как Tomcat 10-й версии, то оставлять надо jakarta. Попробуйте убрать все javax, и посмотрите, какая ошибка будет выдаваться, если будет.

Comment: См. [How to install JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/)

Answer (score 0):

В общем Tomcat 10-ой версии не понимает классы в пакете `javax.*`. По этой причине многие приложения, которые в коде имеют `javax`, и созданные для Java EE ранних версий, которые включают в себя сервлеты и JSP, а также библиотеки тэгов, такие как JSTL, не могут работать на новой версии Tomcat 10. Поэтому требуется переписать код и заменить все ссылки на старые библиотеки, а также обновить версию приложения в дескриптора, если он имеется.

В зависимостях мавена тоже надо поудалять все ссылки на `javax`. В зависимостях, если в приложении используется servlet-api или jsp-api, то пометить надо как `provided`, потому, что на сервере уже есть такие либы, правда они загруженные другим класслоадером, поэтому может возникать ошибка приведения типов в рантайме.

То что касается jstl новой версии, то можно сделать следующее

> ```xml
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
>     <версия>3.0.0</версия>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>
> <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
>     <version>3.0.1</version>
>  </dependency>
> ```

В JSP определить таглиб URI:

> ```
> <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="jakarta.tags.core" %>
> ```

Comment: Ссылку забыл прикрепить :)

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.